# Is there a way to customize JSON serialization when inserting/updating a model in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, serialization, eloquent

I have a model with some json columns. In my seeder, I got something like this:

```php
/* dd($object)
{
    'string_field1': "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ",
    'string_field2': "123",
    'string_field3': "Normal string",
}
*/
MyModel::create([
   'json_column1' => ["{$object->string_attribute1} - {$object->string_attribute2}"],
   'json_column2' => [$object->string_attribute3],
]);
```

My model has the json columns in its casts array

```php
# MyModel.php
protected $casts = [
    'json_column1' => 'array',
    'json_column2' => 'array'
];
```

When I look at the records inserted in the database (PostgreSQL), I see two problems.

- Their values look like arrays
- All unicode characters are escaped

Basically, it's using the `json_encode()` function under the hood with no options and I'd like to pass some options (`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` and `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`) by default without having to explicitly write it every time.

## **TL;DR**

```php
// this
MyModel::create([
   'json_column1' => ["{$object->string_attribute1} - {$object->string_attribute2}"],
   'json_column2' => [$object->string_attribute3],
]);
// automagically converts to this
MyModel::create([
   'json_column1' => json_encode(["{$object->string_attribute1} - {$object->string_attribute2}"]),
   'json_column2' => json_encode([$object->string_attribute3]),
]);
// but I want it to convert to this
MyModel::create([
   'json_column1' => json_encode(["{$object->string_attribute1} - {$object->string_attribute2}"], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
   'json_column2' => json_encode([$object->string_attribute3], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
]);
```

Comment: Try casting as object 

protected $casts = [
    'json_column1' => 'object',
    'json_column2' => 'object'
];

Comment: No changes at all.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L476 shows what happens with the cast types. Looks like I'll have to put it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting properties in the Model instance is effectively just a simplified way of implementing a mutator and an accessor.  So, you could instead remove the cast and define these yourself, granting you any behavior you desire.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

**MyModel.php**

```php
class MyModel extends Model
{
    ...

    // fires when storing a value
    public function setJsonColumn1Attribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['json_column1'] = json_encode([$value], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }

    // fires when retrieving a value
    public function getJsonColumn1Attribute($value)
    {
        return json_decode($value);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```php
MyModel::create([
   'json_column1' => "{$object->string_attribute1} - {$object->string_attribute2}",
]);
```